# Create JSON object using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, system.text.json, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on migrating from Json.Net to System.Text.Json. I am not sure how we can build json object like below code using System.Text.Json. I tried lots of workaround but nothing seems working. I know we can do this using `JsonObject` from Dot net 6 , but I am using Dot net core 5.

Newtonsoft code:

```
var json = new JObject(
    new JProperty("Status", result.Status.ToString()),
    new JProperty("Duration", result.TotalDuration.TotalSeconds.ToString()));
if (result.Entries.Any())
{
    var entries = new JObject(result.Entries
        .Select(d => new JProperty(d.Key, new JObject(new JProperty("Status", d.Value.Status.ToString()), new JProperty("Duration", d.Value.Duration.TotalSeconds.ToString()), new JProperty("Description", d.Value.Description)))));

    json.Add(new JProperty("result", entries));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can  find answer in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0). Besides, what's error do you get ?

Comment: Can you please share with us what you have tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Create a class that represents what you want, then serialize that. For dynamic keys, use a `Dictionary`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET 5 you can use a combination of dictionaries and anonymous types to construct free-form JSON on the fly.  For instance, your sample code can be rewritten for System.Text.Json as follows:

```
var json = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["Status"] = result.Status.ToString(),
    ["Duration"] = result.TotalDuration.TotalSeconds.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
};

var entries = result.Entries.ToDictionary(
    d => d.Key,
    d => new { Status = d.Value.Status.ToString(), Duration = d.Value.Duration.TotalSeconds.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), Description = d.Value.Description } );
if (entries.Count > 0)
    json.Add("result", entries);

var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Notes:

- When constructing a JSON object with properties whose values have mixed types (like the root `json` object in your example) use `Dictionary<string, object>` (or `ExpandoObject`, which implements `Dictionary<string, object>`).

  You must use `object` for the value type because System.Text.Json does not support polymorphism by default unless the declared type of the polymorphic value is `object`.  For confirmation, see *[How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-polymorphism#serialize-properties-of-derived-classes)*:

  > You can get polymorphic serialization for lower-level objects if you define them as type `object`.
- When constructing a JSON object with a fixed, known set of properties, use an anonymous type object.
- When constructing a JSON object with runtime property names but fixed value types, use a typed dictionary.  Oftentimes LINQ's `ToDictionary()` method will fit perfectly, as is shown above.
- Similarly, when constructing a JSON array with values that have mixed types, use `List<object>` or `object []`.  A typed `List<T>` or `T []` may be used when all values have the same type.
- When manually formatting numbers or dates as strings, be sure to do so in the invariant locale to prevent locale-specific differences in your JSON.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5pvxda).